# Will Flex (desktop browser) project export to AIR (desktop) seamlessly, or require tweaking?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm developing a Flex web application for desktop browsers. I have no experience with AIR.

Is it a simple turnkey process to get the Flex application exported to AIR for desktop environment (e.g. I'm not talking about mobile or tablet application here, only desktop)? Or, will I need to re-write the Flex/AS3 code in order to make it work for AIR?

That is, will I need to develop a branch in the code for an AIR application and commit to troubleshooting in the AIR environment, or will 100% of the code work the same in both (desktop browser and AIR desktop) applications?

Comment: It really depends what you're doing and what APIs you're using and how different you want the desktop version to be than the web version.  The answer already posted lists a few caveats including file system operations and JavaScript communications

Comment: Thanks Flextras, I don't want to add any new capabilities in the web app for the AIR version. The two should appear the same. I mainly want to provide an alternative for the user to not require downloading the app each and every time he/she wants to use it. The only difference I can think of is it will require AIR to auto-update when new versions are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will not 100% work.

Off the top of my head the base class of a web-based Flex application is `Application` while an AIR-based Flex app will be `WindowedApplication` (EDIT: reading the docs this may not be *strictly* required as `WindowedApplication` inherits from `Application`). You'll also need to handle things like the application menu (and the fact that this menu is different on Mac and Windows) and situations like the user clicking the "x" close button on the app window.

I would expect the core code for your application to work without any major changes though. If I were doing this I'd branch so that I have "web" and "desktop" versions and look to abstract away the differences (having an `isDesktop()` helper method for instance).

Comment: Thanks for the specific details.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can build an AIR Desktop Application using the Application tag.  You'll miss some of the specific functionality exposed in the WindowedApplication, though.  There is no need for an Application Menu.  I thought that the user clicking the close button was handled automatically (although perhaps that is part of WindowedApplication)

Comment: @www.Flextras.com There might not be a __need__ for an application menu but on Mac OS you'll get one anyway ;)

Comment: @NoobsArePeople2 I think you'll get an application menu on Windows too, but there is no need to write code to accomodate for it.  I believe these can be hidden with a custom chrome.

Comment: Regardless of what the "parent container" is for your air/web application, your code sounds like it will work just fine. Typically, when I do this, I put as much common code into SWC library projects, and create separate application projects that use the SWC's.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not planning any Air specific features (e.g. file system operations) in Air version of your web application and at the same time you are not using any web specific features (e.g. JavaScript to Flash communication), then publishing your web application as an Air application should be smooth. Otherwise it can be tricky.

Comment: Thanks skovalyov, there'll be no file system operations nor JavaScript to Flash communication.